# I need an identity provider with users grouped in independend groups

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

Is there anywhere an OAuth/oidc identity provider (cloud or on-premises) that supports sth. like company groups? I want to group the users in company groups. Every company group should have an company administrator user. The company administrator user should only see the users of his company.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've tried [miniOrange](https://www.miniorange.com/) (Cloud/On-Premise based) who support this Super admin feature and it has worked very well for me. there may be some other Identity Providers in the market like OneLogin, KeyCloak etc. who support this usecase.

In this use case, designating administrators can help you manage your Company Groups and only certain types of administrators can add / remove other admins, post updates, and edit your Company Groups.